# does data-dismiss in angular bootstrap modal work without bootstrap,js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my solution, I am launching an angular ui modal.

I am using a combo of angular ui 0.12, bootstrap.css and angular js 1.2.24.

SInce I am including the ui-bootstrap-0.12.0.js file, I am not including bootstrap.js from the boostrap distribution. I am only using the boostrap.css file.

The x button and the close button both of which have  data-dismiss are not working ie closing.

I am wondering if the jquery  libraries which are included are breaking the data-dimiss functionality

Comment: `ui-bootstrap` has no dependency other than css. `data-dismiss` is not relevant in `ui-bootstrap` . See docs example using `ng-click` for closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui-bootstrap has no `bootstrap.js` dependency , only the css. `data-dismiss` is not relevant in ui-bootstrap .

See docs example using `ng-click` for closing